# Using external js with .php extension in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, fatal-error

I am using codeigniter 2 and I have my theme folder consist of **js**, **img**, **css** folders.

Inside **js** folder, file name is **js_functions.php** contains:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
/**
 * GLOBAL VARIABLES & PATHS
 *
 * path definitions for jquery inline usage
 *
 */     
var base_url         = '<?=base_url();?>';
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * jquery.message Global Implementation
 *
 * Shows message if any session flashdata named message is set
 *
 */

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')):?>
$(function() { $().message("<?=$this->session->flashdata('message');?>"); });
<?php endif; ?>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and, calling in it **view** file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>themes/admin/js/js_functions.php"></script>
```

renders correctly. But it returns in the chrome's inspect screen:

```
var base_url         = '<br />
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

and in the browser when you call the page from address bar:

```
var base_url         = '<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function base_url() in <b>F:\xampp\htdocs\themes\js\js_functions.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

What's wrong? Isn't it the correct way of using php in external js/php file?

Comment: Is `js_functions.php` a standalone file, or does it `include` other files? If it's standalone, how does it know what `base_url()` is?

Comment: @TRiG it doesn't include any file. I think it is the question you mentioned: How can it make know that it is working in codeigniter?

Comment: Well, that's your problem, but I'm not familiar enough with CodeIgnitor to know how to fix it. What do you expect `$this` to be in the context of this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a controller to get the script. May be `js`. Inside your controller you set the content type headers and load the view which contains above javascript. Lets say you have a controller called `js`

```
class Js extends CI_Controller{
  public function js_functions(){
    $this->output->set_header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    $data = array( 'messages' => $this->session->flashdata('message'));
    $this->load->view('jsfunc',$data);
  }
}
```

And you can load the script in the main view like this

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/js_functions'); ?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate dynamic `js`, `css` files. Use standart MVC method. Make a folder in `view` folder with name js or css. Create js or css files as php view file. For example : `slider.js.php`.

Make a controller `themejs.php`. Forward all js or css files to this controller which you need, by using routing. And inside this controller make dynamic action, pass varibles to js, css view files. And print them with header

Comment: Thanks seems I need to seperate them all

Answer (score 0):

`base_url()` is a function part of the CI url helper. If you want to make use of it in that file and you don't want to create an instance of the $CI object, you will have to implement your own version of that function.

Comment: helpmed to identify the real problem, thank you.

Comment: You can also have a look at embedding assetic(https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) into your application. With that combined with the custom controller solution above, you'll manage assets in style.